# error when echo a rostopic when using gazebo_ros package for ros intergration approach

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am using the gazebo_ros packages to build my program with catkin packages and I am publishing two topics one of them I used sensor_msgs::LaserScan , the other topic I built its message that the problem happen with. The  problem is when I use "rostopic echo " on a topic that I built,
I get the following error :

ERROR: Cannot load message class for [angen_gazebo/PirMsg]. Are your messages built?

I dont have a problem using a "rostopic info" in which I get the information of this topic.
Also I can use “rosmsg show” and “rostopic info”  to get the information of the topic.

Meanwhile there is another topic that I publish and am using sensor_msgs::LaserScan type and I can echo its topic without any problem as the previous one.
Note: both  topics showed when using rostopic list

Can anyone help me plz!
thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4185/error-when-echo-a-rostopic-when-using-gazebo_ros-package-for-ros-intergration-approach./) by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 122 on 2013-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/468/zahra/) on 2013-08-22**:
The problem is solved by rebuilding the message by editing CmakeList file dependency and building the project again and sourcing the setup.bash  . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Answer is in the comments.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0